# Batchnormalization in Keras vs PyTorch vs Numpy are different

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

I created the BatchNormalization layer in Keras, PyTorch and calculated the same operation using Numpy but I get three different results. Am I making some error here?

Things I assume below: `layer.get_weights()` in `tf.keras` for BN layer returns in order `gamma, beta, running_mean, running_var`. For the BN operation I am using the following operation: `gamma * (x - running_mean) / sqrt(running_var + epsilon) + beta`

Code snippet to reproduce the issue:

```py
import torch
import tensorflow
from torch.nn import Module, BatchNorm1d, Conv1d
from torch.nn.functional import pad
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, BatchNormalization, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
np.random.seed(12345)

z = Input((1024, 8), dtype=np.float32)
inp = z
z = Conv1D(64, 16, padding='same', use_bias=False)(z)
z = BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001)(z)
keras_model = Model(inp, z)
# in order: conv-layer weight, gamma, beta, running_mean, running_var
weights = [np.random.random((16, 8, 64)), np.random.random((64,)), np.random.random((64,)), np.random.random((64,)),
           np.random.random((64,))]
weights = [np.array(x, dtype=np.float32) for x in weights]
keras_model.layers[1].set_weights([weights[0]])
keras_model.layers[2].set_weights(weights[1:])
keras_model_subpart = Model(keras_model.inputs, keras_model.layers[1].output)


class TorchModel(Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TorchModel, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = Conv1d(8, 64, 16, bias=False)
        self.l2 = BatchNorm1d(64, 0.001)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = pad(x, (7, 8))
        x = self.l1(x)
        y = x
        x = self.l2(x)
        return y, x


torch_model = TorchModel().to(torch.device('cpu'))
torch_model.l1.weight.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[0].T).float()
torch_model.l2.weight.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[1].T).float()
torch_model.l2.bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[2]).float()
torch_model.l2.running_mean = torch.from_numpy(weights[3]).float()
torch_model.l2.running_var = torch.from_numpy(weights[4]).float()
torch_model.eval()

input_value = np.array(np.random.random((1024, 8)), dtype=np.float32)

keras_results = [np.array(keras_model_subpart.predict(input_value[np.newaxis, :, :])),
                 np.array(keras_model.predict(input_value[np.newaxis, :, :]))]
with torch.no_grad():
    torch_results = [x.detach().numpy() for x in torch_model(torch.from_numpy(input_value.T[np.newaxis, :, :]).float())]


keras_results = [np.squeeze(x) for x in keras_results]
torch_results = [np.squeeze(x) for x in torch_results]
numpy_results = weights[1] * (keras_results[0] - weights[3]) / np.sqrt(weights[4] + 0.001) + weights[2]

print(torch.__version__, tensorflow.__version__, np.__version__, sep=",")
print('\nRESULTS:')
print('\tLayer 1 difference:', np.mean(np.abs(keras_results[0] - torch_results[0].T).flatten()))
print('\tLayer 2 difference:', np.mean(np.abs(keras_results[1] - torch_results[1].T).flatten()))
print('\tLayer 2 keras - numpy:', np.mean(np.abs(keras_results[1] - numpy_results).flatten()))
print('\tLayer 2 torch - numpy:', np.mean(np.abs(torch_results[1] - numpy_results.T).flatten()))
```

The output I get (after all the initialization printing of tensorflow)

```
1.7.1+cu110,2.4.1,1.19.5

RESULTS:
        Layer 1 difference: 0.0
        Layer 2 difference: 6.8671216e-07
        Layer 2 keras - numpy: 2.291581e-06
        Layer 2 torch - numpy: 1.8929532e-06
```

Comment: The difference are small and such small difference can happen. Please make sure the every calculation uses the same floating size. Numpy will use 64 bit, python float is 64 bit,  etc but I see some places use dtype=np.float32 but it seems not consistent.

Comment: I suppose you are aware 0.1 is not actually 0.1 etc e.g. print("{:.52f}".format(0.1)) will show it is not 0.1 actually. 0.1 * 3 == 30 / 100 is False. Rounding errors in floating point number can happen in many places.

Comment: @mon I have ensured everything uses 32bit floats here, right? Also, if it was a float-truncation error, should it also not crop up in the convolutional output? Similar calculations on similar precision floats should incur the same rounding afaik. And the size of the error might be small, but on using a deeper network, these accumulate into larger differences especially when the penultimate layer outputs a value close to the high-slope region of the ultimate sigmoid layer.

Comment: e.g. epsilon=0.001. What is the type of 0.001? What is the bit size of this floating point?

Comment: @mon Using `np.array([0.001], dtype=np.float32)[0]`  instead does not change the results

Comment: @mon Also, the concern is just to confirm what implementation difference is causing these differences when the weights and the float-precision are the same, and the algorithm is deterministic. Hopefully, being able to get the same answer everywhere is an added benefit

Comment: We do not exactly know as we do not know what is happening inside the library. All we can use is np.allclose() etc to assure the difference is within an expected/acceptable value ranges. To mitigate numeric errors, reformulations are used as well. Cross entropy log loss -Tlog(x) -(1-T)log(1-sigmoid(x)) can be reformulated into max(x, 0) - x * T + log(1 + exp(-abs(x))), etc. With all such tricks, we can only make sure the differences are within acceptable range.

Comment: Need to accept the fact we cannot expect "==" when it comes to floating point calculations. In banking etc such errors are not acceptable, they use BigInteger, and avoid floating point calculations, although it is slow. Please look into numeric analysis text books for details.